# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CustomersController#new Couldn't find Business without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubymine

so I have looked at other instances of this error in other questions on SO and none seem to be helpful. So, my authentication system should allow a Business to sign up, and allow a user to sign up under their business. However, I'm getting a "couldn't find business without ID" error.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change


    create_table :users do |t|

      t.references :company, foreign_key: true


      t.timestamps
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name

      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :remember_digest
      t.string :role

    end


class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  def new

    set_business

    @customer = @business.customers.create(user_params)

  end

  def create

    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    @customer.save!
    session[:customer_id] = @customer.id
    redirect_to '/'
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => ex
    render action: 'new', alert: ex.message
  end

  private
  def customer_params

    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password_digest, :business_id) 
  end

  def set_business

    @business = Business.find (params[:business_id])

  end



HTML snippet: Customer.new.html.erb

<h1>Sign Up</h1>

      <%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :first_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name" %>
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name" %>
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
          <%= f.label :company_id %>
          <%= f.collection_select :business_id, Business.all, :id, :name %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_digest, :placeholder => "Password" %>
          <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn-submit" %>
      <% end %>



class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers

end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
end
```

How am I supposed to define the @business variable without getting this error so that a user can sign up under their business? I want them to select from a list of available companies on the form, which will then link them in the database when the user signs up. What am I doing wrong? I am very new to Ruby and I may need some good explanation to why this is happening.

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the contents of the params[], since there's no plain :business_id key, it's nested in a :customers hash:

change your set_business to somethink like this:

```
  def set_business

    @business = Business.find (params[:customer][:business_id])

  end
```

EDIT: This will not work, since the first call to new method, the params is not supplied. You should only get a list of businesses to populate the form!

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @businesses = Business.all
end
```

EDIT2: In create method you don't need to set the business either, since it's already set by the form!

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.create(customer_params)
  @customer.save
end
```

Comment: I do that on a daily basis :). Could you mark the answer as the correct solution?

Comment: I have done but I'm too new for it to be displayed I think

Answer (score 0):

Update the `controller`

customers_controller.rb

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_business

  def new
    @customer = @business.customers.build
  end

  def create
    begin
      @customer = @business.customers.new(customer_params)
      @customer.save!
      session[:customer_id] = @customer.id
      redirect_to '/'
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => ex 
      render action: 'new', alert: ex.message
    end
  end

  private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password_digest, :business_id) 
  end

  def set_business
    @business = Business.find (params[:business_id])
  end
end
```